# Notice: Undefined index Repository Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I hope to get Id from table User using repository in my action :

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppMyBundle:User')
    ->findByUsername($token['name']);

 $id = $user['id'];  // also $user->id or $user->getId() give me error?
```

that give me this error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/project/src/App/MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 56
```

finally the var_daump output :

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($user);
exit();
echo "</pre>";


 array(1) {
[0]=>
object(App\MyBundle\Entity\User)#351 (21) {
["id":protected]=>
int(17)
....
....
```

Comment: did `$user->getId()` give you an error? If so, do you have this method inside your `User` class?

Comment: sure I have,I use FosUserBudle for that...

Comment: please if u dont have a good solution dont reply...

Comment: This isn't stricly a SYmfony2 related question. If your `var_dump` is correct, then you haven't working methods for this object: it's logic, my dear. BTW, you can't access to an object with `[]` (array notation)

Comment: I know it's an array but when you dont have a solution you try also the bad one,you do you have a good solution plz if you don't so don't reply

Comment: This arrogance will not bring you an answer, sir. Not from me, neither from another. You want a good answer? First of all, make a good question (this is a poor one, too little code), second: try to be gentle with who tries to help you without asking you a penny. Thank you.

Comment: it's a very simple question,I had a solution to use queryBuilder directly in repository class btu it's not a good one,I hoped a good solution,you don't know anything because I wrote all informations about my issue,now because you answer me with a bad response you stop other people to see my issue,finally you just play...stop

Comment: Have you slimmed down the var_dump at `....`? [The getId() method](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L209) should work, if it is listed in the var_dump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to call `findOneByUsername` method instead of `findByUsername`.

`findBy*` return an array of object and `findOneBy*` return an object.

After this in order to get the id just call your getter `$id = $user->getId();`

Hop it's helpful.

Best regard.